# Criando senha aleatória no banco de dados MySQL

Tags: sql

Bom dia, estou tentando criar uma trigger que gera uma senha aleatória com letras maiúsculas e números de 0-9 em um campo senha do banco de dados, como é possível fazer essa trigger ?

[FUNÇÃO]

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `gerador_senha`() RETURNS char(6) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
  DECLARE Aux VARCHAR(31) DEFAULT '23456789ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  DECLARE Result varchar(6) DEFAULT '';
  REPEAT
    SET Result = CONCAT(Result, SUBSTRING(Aux, FLOOR(RAND() * 31), 1));
  UNTIL LENGTH(Result) = 6
  END REPEAT;
  RETURN Result;
END
```

[TRIGGER]

```
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `vendas`.`before_funcionarios_insert`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `vendas`.`tb_funcionarios`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF (NEW.fun_senha = ' ' or New.fun_senha IS NULL) THEN
    SET NEW.fun_senha = gerador_senha();
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: Forneça mais detalhes do problema e do ambiente (banco , tabelas etc), e provavelmente a melhor solução não passará por trigger.

Comment: questão editada com a resposta